# Initializing PhantomJS Server Outside my IDE

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I've been working on porting my code to a runnable JAR file all day, but I can't seem to get PhantomJS to work. My code looks like this:

```
private void initDriver()
    {
        // Prevent Log Messages from showing up in console, login

        try 
        {
            File f = new File ("./phantomjs.exe");
            if (!f.exists()) 
            {
              wait(2.0);
              InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/js/scrapertool/resources/phantomjs.exe");
              OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./phantomjs.exe");
              IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            }
            System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","./phantomjs.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            try 
            {
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream("output.txt"));
                System.exit(0);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        String[] phantomArgs = new String[] { "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE" };
        dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);


        //Initialize driver, try 3 times before crashing
        int i=0;
        while(i<3)
        {
            try
            {
                driver=new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if(i>2)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream("output.txt"));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //after debugging I know it gets here eventually
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, it copies phantomjs.exe (from my resources package) to an external directory and starts it. This works fine in my IDE, but for some reason I get this error when I try to use `initDriver()`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-NO00B13', ip: '192.168.100.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:105)
    at js.scrapertool.webpages.LinkedIn.initDriver(LinkedIn.java:258)
    at js.scrapertool.webpages.LinkedIn.login(LinkedIn.java:39)
    at js.scrapertool.main.Main.login(Main.java:47)
    at js.scrapertool.gui.windows.Login$4.doInBackground(Login.java:151)
    at js.scrapertool.gui.windows.Login$4.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:14791/status] to be available after 20002 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
    ... 21 more
```

After debugging I know it's at least finding the phantomjs.exe server file, so what should I do?

UPDATE:

Tried this today and it worked. Maybe I just needed to reset my computer.

Comment: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:14791/status] to be available after 20002 ms` - it seems you are loading wrong page?